# GDB remote debug: can't stop the thread

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I have a *gdbserver* on a target, that I launch like `gdbserver :2345 /bin/ls`. Next I am connect a gdb from a host, and trying issue next commands:

```
(gdb) target remote 192.168.1.2:2345
Remote debugging using 192.168.1.2:2345
warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
[New Thread 686]
(gdb) Remote 'g' packet reply is too long: 00000000c10ed6be0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d00dd6be0000000030fe0d40100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
(gdb) i thr
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 686        (running)
(gdb) interrupt
(gdb) interrupt 1
(gdb) interrupt 2
(gdb) i thr
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 686        (running)
(gdb) bt
Target is executing.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Cannot execute this command while the selected thread is running.
```

I thought that may be the reason of a broken gdb is the weird message, tried to Google. Found two assumptions. [Here's a man](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/RemoteGPacketReplyIsTooLong)  supposes that the *gdb* (despite IMHO that on the target is running the *gdbserver* that should send an abstract arch-independent commands) need the architecture that it is debugs to be set. But it doesn't work:

```
(gdb) set architecture armv7-a
Undefined item: "armv7-a".
(gdb) set architecture armv7
Undefined item: "armv7".
(gdb) set architecture armv5te
Undefined item: "armv5te".
```

I didn't found any command that could list supported architectures. The [second assumption](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2011-05/msg00108.html) was that the *gdbserver* itself needs to be configured with a mythological option `--with-expat`. But... `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-expat`

I have no more ideas. So, do anybody knows: how to interrupt the thread on the target?(Btw, breakpoints could be set just fine, but it doesn't help at all, because seems that the gdb is lying about a running thread. If the thread would running, the being debugged `ls` just gone immediately.)

Comment: What version of GDB are you running on your host?

Comment: @dbrank0, `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1-ubuntu`.

Comment: So it's gdb for your host PC. You need appropriate build for your target. You should get that with your toolchain, but if not, it's not hard to build from source (see https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingCrossGDBandGDBserver).

Comment: @dbrank0 so, is this means that the gdb and gdbserver should be the same version? Or why am I need to build the gdb too? Right now the gdbserver for a target is built from a sources, and the gdb on a host is the one from Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Yes, while it is possible to build "multiarch" gdb, default Ubuntu gdb (called gdb only) is built to support single architecture - host PC. You need gdb that can debug ARM and is compatible with ABI used on your target.

Comment: @dbrank0 that is it! You may post an answer, I just compiled the GDB from a sources too, and all works out-of-the-box. Apparently it was a bug: instead of reporting about an unsupported architecture it just refused to work.

Comment: Ok, reposted as short answer. BR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to build "multiarch" gdb, default Ubuntu GDB (called gdb) is built to support single architecture - host PC. You can not debug other CPUs with it, although it does connect to any gdbserver.

You need gdb that can debug your target (ARM) and is compatible with ABI used on your target.

You should get that with your toolchain, but if not, it's not hard to build from source. See [sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingCrossGDBandGDBserver](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingCrossGDBandGDBserver) for brief instructions.

Answer (score 2):

In order to check which architecture your GDB currently support (those you can have in a `set architecture` command), just type:

```
(gdb) set architecture
```

without any arguments... As simple as that.
Otherwise, you'll probably need a cross GDB, as mentioned by @drbank0.

Comment: Yeah, it just was a bit irrational that remotely gdb does only support a specific architecture — because all the machine dependent commands being executed by the gdbserver, not the gdb itself.